# How to cancel HTML "onfocus" behavior?

Tags: html, css, onfocus

What would cause a browser to plaster a "focus halo" around an HTML element when it is clicked?

This is happening on a custom button bar (think radio buttons) that uses  elements + CSS styles to reflect button state. When one of spans is clicked Chrome is wrapping an orange line around it, whereas Firefox is using a black dotted line.

I know it sounds stupid-simple, and probably is, but it's giving me fits trying to identify where this behavior is coming from - as for some this is the only component within the entire application that suffers from this browser behavior.

Any ideas where/how to stop the browser from doing this?

FWIW, this is sole listener attachment, and the behavior continues even when it is removed:

```
  tab.addEventListener("mousedown", this.e_tabMouseDown, false)
```

Per posted suggestions, the CSS has been modified to include with these additions:
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

but the problem is still persisting. To be more specific, this behavior isn't highlighting any selected text - it's just drawing a focus box where it's not wanted.

UPDATE ANSWER:
While the CSS mods suggested above will get rid of text highlighting, the focus "halo" can be knocked out with this style rule:   outline: none;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the CSS mods suggested in the linked post will get rid of text highlighting, the focus "halo" can be knocked out with this style rule:

outline: none;

Answer (score 0):

This is the browser's default behavior and can be over-ridden using CSS. See the answer to this question: [How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Comment: Thank you. Any ides as to why are none of the other site elements having this behavior - and not a single one of them uses any type of CSS setting mentioned in that post. (Including other span buttons.) For example, the page I'm debugging has 13 other buttons on it - none of which get that highlight when clicked?

Comment: The CSS modification didn't help - the question has been edited to reflect the CSS changes.